# How can efficiently derive $x$ and $y$ from $z$ where $z=2^x+3^y$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How can efficiently derive $x$ and $y$ from $z$ where $z=2^x+3^y$.
Note. $x$,$y$ and $z$ are integer values and $z$ is $4096$ bits integer or even more.

For all $z>1$.

And if equation be $z$=$2^x$.$3^y$ then what is your answer?

Comment: Do we know anything about $z$ or it can be anything?

Comment: The value of $z$ is between 2 and infinite.

Comment: Then I guess we are talking about numerical methods here... Or in other words you are asking how one can write an arbitrary integer as the sum of a power of 2 and of 3... Interesting question...

Comment: Bear in mind that there are not always solutions. It's clearest when $z$ is a power of $2$ or $3$, but they are not the only exceptions. $6$ and $12$ are some other early failures.

Comment: And if equation be $z$=$2^x$.$3^y$ then what is your answer?

Comment: In case of $z=2^x 3^y$ it's simple factorization. $x$ can be extracted from binary by counting the zero bits at the right hand size, $y$ can be extracted by repetitive division until the remainder stops being zero. If any factors other than 2 and 3 are present, there's no solution (when you divide out all the factors of 2 and 3, you don't get 1).

Answer (score 3):

We don't know which, but either $2^x$ is larger or $3^y$ is larger. (They can't be equal.)

- Suppose $3^y$ is larger. Then, when you write $z$ in base $3$, you'll see a $1$ in the $y$th position, the rest of the digits correspond to the power of $2$. To put this differently: take the largest power of $3$ less than $z$, and suppose it is $3^y$. Then if $z - 3^y$ is a power of $2$, you are done.
- Suppose $2^x$ is larger. Then when you write $z$ in base $2$, you'll see a $1$ in the $x$th position, and the rest of the digits correspond to the power of $3$. Algorithmically: take the largest power of $2$ less than $z$, call it $2^x$, and check whether $z - 2^x$ is a power of $3$.

This is sufficient to be an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: Take $z \equiv 2^{x}\mod 3$. What are the powers of two modulo $3$? Can you spot a pattern?

Here's an example: Let, say, $z=1105$. So we want to find non-negative integers $x,y$ with $z=2^{x}+3^{y}$ (presumably we are given that this is possible). Consider the equation modulo 3.
$$z \equiv 2^{x} \mod 3 \quad \mbox{and}\quad 1105 \equiv 1 \mod 3$$
Now consider the sequence $2^{n} \mod 3$ for $n =0,1,2 \ldots$: the terms alternate $1,2,1,2 \ldots$; $1$ if $n$ is even and $2$ if $n$ is odd - so we can say that $x$ is *even* in our case above - let us write $x=2a$.

Therefore, we have that $z=4^{a}+3^{y}$. Take the equation modulo 4 now and apply a similar procedure. Repeat until it is obvious to halt (and it *is* obvious).

Comment: They alternate $-1$ and $1$, but I don't think this helps much.

Comment: I have elaborated - is my method more obvious now?

Comment: Hmm, it's not clear what happens at the next step: say we get $y$ to be even. Then you consider powers of $4$ mod $9$? Doesn't the number of cases get large, if you're considering say, powers of $64$ mod $81$? But I agree that this can be a method.

Comment: That was my method; I'm not sure how many cases there are at each step, but yes it does seem like it would increase pretty rapidly. When you consider mod 64 the idea that one should halt is that we end up with a term of the form $81\cdot (9^{8})^{d}$, but then $d$ must be $0$ since $9^{8d}>1105$ for larger values.

Answer (score 0):

If $z = 2^x \ 3^y$, then define $a_k = {\log_2 (z) \over{2^k}}$ rounded to the nearest integer.

Let $k = 2$ and $\beta = a_1$

If $ z \equiv_{2^\beta} 0$, $\beta \to \beta + a_k$

Else, $\beta \to \beta - a_k$

Regardless, $k \to k+1$

Repeat until $a_k = 0$, then $x \in \{\beta-1, \beta, \beta+1 \}$ (simple to check which)

After you know $x$, it becomes clear that $y = \log_3 ({z \over{2^x}})$

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the solution doesn't exist. As others pointed out, if $z=0\mod 3$, then there's no solution.

If $z=\pm 1 \mod 3$, then you have $x$ that is even (plus)/ odd (minus). Even if $z$ has 4k bits, it's still reasonable to try all $x$ (2048 checks are no big deal).

5-minute python code (if no arg given, just goes through first million), printing all solutions it finds:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
#check if a power of 3
def check_3(z):
    y=0
    while z%3 == 0:
       y+=1
       z/=3
    return y if z==1 else None

def fun(z):
    if z%3 == 0:
        return None

    if z%3 == 2:
        x=1
        xfactor=2
    else:
        x=0
        xfactor=1
    while xfactor<z:
        remainder=z-xfactor
        if remainder%3 == 0:
            y=check_3(remainder)
            if y:
                return (x,y)

        x+=2
        xfactor*=4

    return None


if len(sys.argv)>1:
    z=int(sys.argv[1])
    r=fun(z)
    if r:
        x,y=r
        print(z,x,y)
    else:
        print(z,"no solution")
else:
    for z in range(1,2<<20):
        r=fun(z)
        if r:
            x,y=r
            print(z,x,y)
```